# Double tap interval time standard

Tags: click, touch, double, zooming, tap

Is there any standard, say ISO standard, for interval (in miliseconds) between to taps ( clicked on touch devices) which assumed as double tap?
I guess it should be long enough to allow slower users to double tap, but not so long that leads to mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is similar to the click/dbl-click issue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-click#Speed_and_timing

> The maximum delay required for two consecutive clicks to be interpreted as a double-click is not standardized. According to Microsoft's MSDN website, the default timing in Windows is 500ms (one half second).

So, apparently, **it's not standardized**. I'd say *tapping* is slower or equal to *clicking* (it will depend on the relative position of the hand to the device), but still 500ms sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Speculation :)

Probably not.  Something this central to the "feel" of a UI would not translate well across different input device types, or even different builds of the same device type.

For example, one touch-screen might be much more sensitive than another.  Another device might be more erratic, and require more software "de-bouncing", and hence more time to make the double-tap distinction.

Also, this setting is usually configurable for greater accessibility by those who are less dexterous (e.g. children, elderly, and the disabled).

For a direct counter-example, in Windows, it is configurable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is, nobody adheres to it.  I believe most systems allow some sort of configuration for this.  Some people (even with old systems that use mice) can't physically click fast enough to trigger a DoubleClick.  They have to modify the system settings.